# Is there a way to exit the process if any Fiber encounters an exception?

Tags: exception, crystal-lang

Right now I have a couple of fibers with loops:

```
spawn {
  begin
    loop { }
  rescue e : MyType
  end
}
```

I'm using `begin/rescue` in them to catch exceptions, print a message, and exit the process. Is there a way to specify only once to catch any exception throughout the running program instead of using `begin/rescue` repeatedly in each different fiber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Any unhandeled exception inside a fiber is rescued and printed to stderr. If you need to do something else, you'll have to catch the exception inside the fiber body.

Comment: This is actually a big problem for me. If a library I am using spawns a thread and it gets an unhandled exception theres nothing I can do about it. This puts the program in an undefined, broken state. A fatal error is a far better option in many use cases.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example of a fiber spawned by a shard putting the program in an undefined state?

Comment: Story time: A few days ago I reported a bug encountered while using `amqp.cr`.. It was that SSL sockets threw an error reading/writing 0-byte packets. When this occurred, the reader thread would stop receiving bytes, and ate a full CPU. Had to sigkill it every time. The worst part is that the thread has exception handlers, but the rescue block crashed(!) trying to print the application backtrace (couldn't open the executable?).. Complicated, right? You can't fix everything. But even a global error handler could have at the very least, shutdown the app.

Comment: This concrete example sounds like a flaw in the shard implementation. But certainly, proper error handling would help avoiding such issues. I've actually been working on a proposal to introduce structured concurrency into Crystal. I'll publish a RFC soon.

Comment: No, the problem was in `ex.backtrace` throwing an error, which was completely unforeseen. That's the point though; You can't cover everything in every scenario -- even exceptions can have exceptions. The real fix is to change crystal so it can handle this as gracefully as possible depending on the app. A GUI program should throw up an error dialog. A web daemon should probably crash, etc.. The only way to handle every case is to improve thread error handling. Even being able to override the default event loop handler would be a massive help.

Comment: @JohannesMüller it's been about 5 years, is this still the situation today?

Comment: Yes. This is still accurate.